# EntryPointNotFoundException: SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacksArgument_DatabaseInternal

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

[image]

I'm getting all my firebaseapp details with my debugs but when it came in the reference line it always show this error "EntryPointNotFoundException: SWIGRegisterExceptionCallbacksArgument_DatabaseInternal". [image]

My database rules is set to true so I can actually read and write. I'm so confused to what is happening. All of my dependencies are available and I have resolve all of my other external dependencies.